# mulitple rows of table having input tag

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-applications

in a invoice form i have a table of which 25 rows are

```
<table border="1"  align="center">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>#</th>
<th>Item Name</th>
<th>Item Code</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Amount</th>-->
<th>Net Amount</th>
</tr>
</thead>

 <tbody>
 <?php for($i=1 ; $i<=25 ; $i++) { ?>

 <tr>
 <th> <?php echo "$i"; ?> </th>
 <td><input id="itemName"  onBlur="loadAllField()" class="orderInput" type="text" align="center" ></td>
 <td><input id="itemCode" onBlur="loadAllField()"  class="orderInput" type="text" align="center" ></td>
<td><input id="quantity" class="orderInput" onKeyPress="calqtyprice()" type="text"         align="center" ></td>
<td><input id="price" class="orderInput" type="text" align="center"  readonly></td>
<td><input id="netAmount" class="orderInput" type="text" align="center" readonly ></td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>
</tbody>

<tfoot>
<tr>
<td id="tdTotal" colspan="2" style="font-size:16px"> <b>Totals</b></td>
<td id="totalspace" colspan="3"> </td>
<td><input id="netTotalAll" class="orderInput" type="text" readonly> </td>
</tr>


</tfoot>
</table>

<p id="msg" align="center"> </p>
```

and the java script functions are

```
 function loadAllField ()
{
    var itemName = document.getElementById("itemName");
var itemCode = document.getElementById("itemCode");
var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity");
var price = document.getElementById("price");
var netAmount = document.getElementById("netAmount");
var msg = document.getElementById("msg");

    msg.innerHTML = "";
// check is fill 
if ( ( (itemName == null ) || (itemName.value == "") ) && ((itemCode == null ) || (itemCode.value == "")) )
{
msg.innerHTML = "";
    itemName.value = null;
    itemCode.value =  null;
    quantity.value = null;
    price.value = null;
    netAmount.value = null;
}

// load id if item name give and load name if item code given

if ((itemName.value == "detol") || (itemCode.value=="1") ) 
{
        var itemName = document.getElementById("itemName");
var itemCode = document.getElementById("itemCode");
var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity");
var price = document.getElementById("price");
var netAmount = document.getElementById("netAmount");
var msg = document.getElementById("msg");
    msg.innerHTML = "";
    itemName.value = "detol";
    itemCode.value = "1";
    quantity.value = "";
    price.value = "40";
    netAmount.value = "";

}

else if  ( (itemName.value == "robin") || (itemCode.value == "2") )  
    {
        msg.innerHTML = "";
    itemName.value = "robin";
    itemCode.value = "2";
    quantity.value = "";
    price.value = "90";
    netAmount.value = "";
    }

    else
    {   
    msg.innerHTML = "Product not find";
    //msg.innerHTML.blink();
    itemName.value = "";
    itemCode.value = "";
    quantity.value = "";
    price.value = "";
    netAmount.value = "";

    }

} // end of load id function

function calqtyprice()
{
    for ( i=1; i==25; i++)
    {

    var price = document.getElementById("price");
    var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity");
    var netAmount = document.getElementById("netAmount");
    var netTotalAll = document.getElementById("netTotalAll");

    var netamt = price.value * quantity.value ;

     netAmount.value = netamt;

    netTotalAll = netAmount.value + netAmount.value;
    }
}
```

the problem is how to go through every row and getting values from input and calculate and show nettotal in the last row.

Or is there any mechanism for this or tutorial.

Comment: You're creating elements with the same ID inside the loop. ID's are unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume you created elements with unique `ids` as follows

```
<input type="text" id="price_1"
```

in your case you can use the `$i` value to create uniqly named ids.

```
<input type="text" id="price_<?php echo $i; ?>"
```

then in your javascript loop

```
for ( i=1; i<=25; i++) {
   var price = document.getElementById("price_" + i);
```

gives you access to each unique element.

Comment: whats the 5 minute grace period?

Comment: @stano sir which i==25 print no line  ??

Comment: @DevZer0 i have done this in javascript funtion but its not working in html. in input tag onblur funtion not calling function.  how to tackle this...?

Comment: @WaleedEhsan what's the status what you need help with?

Comment: @WaleedEhsan here it is, I hope it can be useful :-) http://pastebin.com/PdaQZCf0